No module named pipx
I want to install a streamdeck-linux-gui. the command looks like: python -m pipx install streamdeck-linux-gui. The command spills error: No module named pipx

The starting point for understanding what you're running is what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're using. What are you running that you'd like help with? Different Ubuntu products have different capabilities available, and different requirements/commands.

pipx is not included with a stock install of Ubuntu. You must install it. This suggests that you might be following old instructions or wrong-distro instructions or something else that has put you onto a wrong path.

There's no comment so I don't see how this question is unclear. There's a command that generated an error message when trying to install streamdeck-linux-gui.

The correct commands should be as follows.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pipx
pipx install streamdeck-linux-gui

streamdeck-linux-gui is a Linux compatible UI for the Elgato Stream Deck. This project is a fork and drop-in replacement for streamdeck_ui, which is no longer maintained.
pipx executes binaries from Python packages in isolated environments. That's why you don't need to preface pipx install with sudo if you're just installing a package for the current user.
